# SQL Query invalid/not displaying results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am working on a property management software projects and I have been stuck at this point for a while now and I'm getting no where.

I can have one section working then another breaks so I'm chasing my tail here.

I'm trying to accomplish a form to search a database for specific entries such as bedrooms/baths, maxrent/minrent, and sorting functions included in the form.

**SQL**,

```
$beds = $_POST['beds'];
$baths = $_POST['baths'];
$minrent = $_POST['minrent'];
$maxrent = $_POST['maxrent'];

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM units WHERE bed LIKE '%$beds%' OR bath LIKE '%$baths%' AND rent>='$minrent' AND rent<='$maxrent'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){}
```

Any help to the correct formatting of the sql would be fantastic.  Thanks

**EDIT:**  This is just a local project, not trying to make it web-safe.
Also, the columns I am using are rent, bed, bath with ~150 records.

**EDIT:** Solved, changed the column type from TEXT to INT.

Comment: You've not given the structure of the database, and your code is wide open to SQL injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this, Added `(` for OR `)`

```
"SELECT * FROM units WHERE (bed LIKE '%$beds%' OR bath LIKE '%$baths%') 
 AND (rent between '$minrent' AND '$maxrent' )"
```

Comment: This works, but only sometimes.  Is it possible that the range is between the numbers is too much ($600 difference in min and max) that it won't show the results?  Thanks!

Comment: The range would not be an issue.

Comment: Is there a code I can insert to get what the cause it for this?